# Firebase authentication Rule on Database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have to implement a rule in my Firebase Database in order to prevent unauthorized access (read, write).

In my db I have a collection of words. Each word has a "uid" field that corresponds to the uid of the authUser key in local Storage.
In my REST call to Firebase I pass the parameter uid:

```
const urlByUser = 'orderBy="uid"&equalTo="'+uid+'"';
```

I implemented the following ".read" rule in Firebase db but it's not working (I get unathourized access; of course I pass also the access token as a parameter in the URL):

```
{
  "rules": {
      "words": {
      ".indexOn": ["uid"],
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong in the rule?
Thanks

Comment: if you use FirebaseAuth it will detect that you are authenticated, after that in your rules you should add ".read":"auth!=null",  ".write":"auth!=null"

Comment: Hi @GastónSaillén, I don't want to check only if the auth!=null but also that the uid in the URL is the same of the auth.uid (where auth.id is calculated from the access token encrypted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a query on a location, requires that you have read access to that entire location. This means that rules themselves cannot be used to filter data.

What you can do (a very recent addition) however is write rules that determine what queries are allowed in a certain location. In your case that would mean that you allow reading from `/words`, but only *if they query filtering by `auth.uid`*. So you'll have a rule that allows a correctly filtered query, but that rejects an unfiltered (or incorrectly filtered) listener.

Read more about that feature in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules) and on the Firebase blog in [Introducing Query-based Security Rules](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html). Modified from there:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "words": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
                  query.orderByChild == 'uid' &&
                  query.equalTo == auth.uid"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Frank, it works! Thanks a lot for your hint. I used query.orderBy instead of query.orderByChild. Can you explain me the difference please?